# cPanel Backup Solution by Directory

Tags: backup, cpanel

I'd like a backup solution for some servers running cPanel/WHM, it can be free or paid (more likely, if such a solution even exists).

It has to support the following:

- Work within cPanel/WHM (as a plug-in); no standalone stuff
- Everything the default cPanel/WHM backup solution supports
- Full (compressed) and incremental backup by directory + DBs – basically so I can give it directories (within a single account) that it will treat like WHM treats separate accounts and back them up separately.
- All of the above should be possible for remote backups, including remote incremental backups
- Be an active project (in constant development, within reason) with a possibility for technical support